# UIElement position relative to Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, position, uielement

In WPF, I want to get the corner location of a `TabControl` in my code, so I can set a ToolWindow's location accordingly when shown.

How do I get the location of a given `UIElement`?

```
buildingInfoWindow = new BuildingInfoWindow(); // BuildingWindow : System.Windows.Window
buildingInfoWindow.Owner = this;

//buildingInfoWindow.Left = ?; // relative X coordinate of my TabControl
//buildingInfoWindow.Top = ?; // relative Y coordinate of my TabControl
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Point pt = tabControl.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), windowInstance);
```